# How to group start date and end date of multiple records within the same range with sql

Tags: sql, group-by, rank

I have a query that returns me some records as below:

```
ip; start_date; end_date
0.0.0.0; 09/10/2018 00: 00: 00; 10/10/2018 01:00:00
0.0.0.0; 10/10/2018 00: 00: 00; 11/10/2018 01:00:00
0.0.0.0; 10/10/2018 00: 00: 00; 11/10/2018 02:00:00
0.0.0.0; 10/10/2018 00: 00: 00; 11/10/2018 03:00:00
0.0.0.0; 10/10/2018 00: 00: 00; 11/10/2018 05:00:00
0.0.0.0; 10/12/2018 00: 00: 00; 10/10/2018 04:00:00
```

As you can see, I have some records that if we grouped by the start and end dates, they would be within the same period;

how to group in a query to get the records as follows:

```
0.0.0.0; 09/10/2018 00: 00: 00; 11/10/2018 05:00:00
0.0.0.0; 10/12/2018 00: 00: 00; 10/10/2018 04:00:00
```

As you can see, the first 5 lines are contained within the same range and the last line is not.

Comment: The last range appears to have end_date before start_date

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Aside from Nicks observation... you want two intervals to be in the same group under which condition? That there is a "path of overlapping intervals" between them? Well, this would smell like a recursive-with-statement or sth like it, I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a cumulative max() to see where there are overlaps.  Where there is no overlap, then a group begins.  A cumulative sum of the beginning determines each "island" and the final step is aggregation:

```
select ip, grp,
       min(start_date), max(end_date)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_max_end_date >= start_date
                      then 0 else 1
                 end) over (partition by ip order by start_date) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   max(end_date) over (partition by ip 
                                       order by start_date
                                       rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
                                      ) as prev_max_end_date
            from t
           ) t
      ) t
group by ip, grp;
```